# can jquery do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.each(3,function(i){
    alert(i)
    })
```

alert 0,1,2

how to do this using jquery?

thanks

Comment: Regardless of the answer, I get the feeling that this is a good example of "just because you can doesn't mean you should".

Comment: You can also do this with logic circuits, but better to do with pure js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$.each iterates over an array or object, so you'd want to make an array...

```
$.each([0,1,2],function(i){alert(i);});
```

Edit: If you want a function to make the array for you, up to a maximum number, here's one way:

```
max=5;

$.each(
  (function(){ i=0,f=[]; while(i<max){ f.push(i);i++; } return f;})(),
  function(i){ alert(i); }
  );
```

Answer (score 6):

Is this question for another type of example?  If not, why not just use a plain old boring javascript loop?

```
for( var i=0; i<3; i++ ) {
    alert(i);
}
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1):

How about you define your own `each`:

```
jQuery.extend({
    eachIter: function(to,callback){
        for(var i=0;i<to;i++){
            callback(i);
        }
    }
});
```

Then you can call it as you said:

```
$.eachIter(3,function(i){alert(i);});
```

Comment: You should pass the `i` variable to the callback, not the `to` variable, otherwise it will alert 3, three times.